# OpenLayers: Loading a TileJSON from a local file

Tags: ios, json, cordova, openlayers-3

I'm trying to implement a local copy of a TileJSON in an iOS app through Cordova. The issue I'm having is that OpenLayers doesn't seem to recognise the JSON file as valid and thus doesn't show any tiles. I have tried local and remote versions of the same TileJSON and looked at the Console Logs, the local one has a status of "error" (but no explanation as to what that error might be...).

I think the issue is down to the fact that the JSON file is being loaded using a `file:` URL, rather than `http:`. I have put the JSON file on a remote server and this not only loads fine but actually loads the tiles from the local path.

Can OpenLayers be tricked into accepting the local file as a valid JSON file? Can Cordova be forced to load local files via HTTP? I think either of these options would fix the issue.

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using to load the TileJSON:

```
var mapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
        url: getPhoneGapPath() + 'tiles.json',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    })
});
this.map.addLayer(mapLayer);

function getPhoneGapPath() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
    return path;
}
```

The `getPhoneGapPath()` function is used to get the path to the webroot of the Cordova app.

Comment: Please show me your code through which you are read tilejson file.

Comment: I Hassan, I've updated the question with the code that loads the local TileJSON. There isn't anything really out of the ordinary with this code (apart from the path function which does load the JSON file, it just isn't processed by OpenLayers).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to a bug in OpenLayers, https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5647. The fix will be in the next release.

Also make sure that you configure Cordova to allow access to file:// urls when the application is served from a file:// url. The equivalent option in Chrome is `--allow-file-access-from-files`.